# Get text from nested div tags using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium webdriver on gmail signup web application to extract the text(month names like january, february...) from Birthday Month field. code is shown as below:

```html
<label id="month-label" class="month">
  <span id="BirthMonth" class=" form-error" aria-invalid="true">
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" role="listbox" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant=":0" title="Birthday">
      <div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical" style="-moz-user-select: none; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: -299.133px; display: none;" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true">
        <div id=":1" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
          <div class="goog-menuitem-content">January</div>
        </div>
        <div id=":2" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
          <div class="goog-menuitem-content">February</div>
        </div>
        <div id=":3" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
          <div class="goog-menuitem-content">March</div>
          </div>
        <div id=":4" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
          <div class="goog-menuitem-content">April</div>
        </div>
        <div id=":5" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div id=":6" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div id=":7" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div id=":8" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div id=":9" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div id=":a" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div id=":b" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div id=":c" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
      </div>
    <input id="HiddenBirthMonth" name="BirthMonth" type="hidden">
    </span>
</label>
```

I tried suing xpath and other element locators but not able to extract the text. When I use the Select class, I'm getting error `cannot apply select with div`. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: share your code what you have tried

Comment: Tried the following code:                                                                         Select months = new Select(driver.findbyelement(By.xpath("//div[@class=''goog-menu goog-menu-vertical]/div")));

List <WebElement> months_options = months.getOptions();


for(int i=0;i<months_options.getSize();i++)
{
System.out.println(months_options.get(i).getText());
}

Comment: You can't use `Select()` with `div` elements, use simple `click()` instead

Comment: Hi Anderson, My requirement is to get the months text from the nested div tags. Click() is to click on particular month right..?

Comment: `click()` to open drop-down, `click()` to select required option... Just like you do it manually

Comment: Hi Anderson.. Thanks for quick response.. I want to dynamically click on the text month... For this I want to collect all the months list in List and perform the if condition operation. But the problem is, iam unable to get the months text list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you have to do:
The month item is a Bootstrap Dropdown. So you have to traverse through it to get the list. Here is the working code:

```
package Gmail;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class gmailLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='link-signup']/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        List<WebElement> month_menu = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='goog-menuitem-content']"));
        for (int i=0;i<month_menu.size();i++)
        {
            WebElement element = month_menu.get(i);
            String contents = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
            System.out.println("Values from dropdown is : "+contents);
        }
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Definately will try and let you know the status..

Comment: Thanks Dev..your logic is simple and worked smoothly... you made my day.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you. Thanks.